# Analyzing effects of various variables (displacement, horsepower, weight, cylinders, acceleration, etc.) on Miles Per Gallon of Cars in R

Tags: r

I am trying to analyze the mpg dataset from UCI (https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/auto+mpg).

I made a tree and found that apparently the displacement and horsepower are the two explanatory variables that effect the response (mpg) the most. I am now trying to use either multiple regression, ANOVA, model reduction, etc. to somehow support this but keep getting errors when trying to generate models for the dataset. Any idea what would be the best way to approach this in order to generate some statistical evidence that those two in fact effect the response variable the most? Thanks very much in advance. Here is a sample of the data (which is also found at the link provided):

```
MPG CYL DISPLACE    HPWR    WEIGHT  ACCL    YEAR    MAKE    MODEL
18  8   307          130    3504    12       70   chevrolet chevelle malibu
15  8   350          165    3693    11.5     70    buick    skylark 320
18  8   318          150    3436    11       70   plymouth  satellite
16  8   304          150    3433    12       70     amc    rebel sst
17  8   302          140    3449    10.5     70    ford     torino
15  8   429          198    4341    10       70    ford     galaxie 500
14  8   454          220    4354    9        70   chevrolet     impala
14  8   440          215    4312    8.5      70    plymouth   fury iii
14  8   455          225    4425    10       70    pontiac      catalina
15  8   390          190    3850    8.5      70      amc    ambassador dpl
15  8   383          170    3563    10       70     dodge   challenger se
```

Comment: Please share with us the nature and examples of the errors you experience.

Comment: Well I used plot(DISPLACE,MPG,cex=0.5)  etc to plot each of the explanatory variables against mpg to see positive/negative/any correlation. Then I tried generating linear models and fitting to them using lm( ) and I got some significant p-values.. I'm just not sure if that's the best way to see which one effects the mpg the most and if so im not entirely sure how to even interpret them 100% correctly